# Linux Dual Boot /boot, /home and /dev partition sharing

Tags: linux, partition, grub, multiboot

I was thinking about hopping Linux distros and was wondering if there was a way to ***keep my files, my grub and my device mounts*** when I change the distro.

This is so that I can resume my work on the system without having to backup my file system again and again.
I searched and found some answers but then there are other answers that contradict them.

PS : I am thinking of starting with manjaro with xfce and debian with kde. And I want the /home to be common.

Comment: What are the contradictions you're talking about?

Comment: Some people are saying it's fine to share the /home partition. While others are saying that different OSs will make different changes to it and will ultimately harm it.

Comment: Some people are saying it's fine to share the /home partition. While others are saying that different OSs will make different changes to it and will ultimately harm it.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I should have been more careful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can share `/home` across systems, with some caveats. The files in `/home` don't depend on the distribution as such. However, some programs store files in a format that depends on the version, and are not capable of switching between versions: once you've run version N+1 of program X, you may have trouble running version N. This can be a problem if you switch to a distribution that has an older package for some programs. Most programs can cope and just ignore any unknown option, but a few programs refuse to start or trash the configuration. Common culprits are the Gnome desktop environment and the Firefox and Chromium/Chrome web browsers.

In principle you can share the bootloader between Linux distributions. However, each distribution comes with its own bootloader management system. If you want to share, you have to bypass the distribution bootloader management and configure some things manually. It's easier to let each distribution manage its own.

- In all the distributions except one, keep `/boot` on the same partition as `/`, and install Grub on that distribution's partition.
- In one distribution install Grub on the disk's boot sector, and chainload all the other Grub installations. If your computer boots with UEFI, you can use that as the mechanism to choose the OS at boot time instead of Grub.

`/dev` is an in-memory filesystem. Sharing doesn't even apply. What you're calling “device mounts” doesn't come from `/dev`, but from entries in `/etc/fstab` or from some configuration in a desktop environment.

Even for playing around, multiboot is not a very nice experience. I strongly recommend not to do it on your main computer. Do it on a “play” computer if you want, but don't count on maintaining any configuration there, and access your files through the network. To play with multiple distributions, use virtual machines instead. Multiboot was what we did twenty years ago when virtual machines weren't an option. Use one distribution as the host; pick a stable one, not a rolling release, because that's the one you definitely don't want to break. Install the others in their own VM.

Answer (score 1):

This is an answer that'll depend alot on the various distros and their peculiarities w.r.t. the handling of `/etc/fstab` data, and how they'll all want to interact with `/boot` (i.e. grub/LILO/etc.) with the assumptions that they are the only ones in control of that `/boot` directory… The problem is when you want to use the GRUB to choose the distributions, *you* will have to take control of that, *and know what you have to do* to not have the next Debian kernel upgrade overwrite your Manjaro configurations, that'll be the main challenge given your statement/request to "**keep... my grub...**"

If I were to do this, I'll pick my "main" distribution, and do the initial installation with it, and typically have a `/boot` on a separate partition, as well as the `/home` and other "**device mounts**"

Then I'll install the secondary OS, but here I'll be careful to also have a separate `/boot`, but make sure it's separate from the main one, and that you don't break/install the grub on the main distro's `/boot`, and you point `/home` to the main distro's `/home` but make sure you don't format it.

After the secondary distro installation, I'll boot in the main distro, I'll add the needed mounts in `/etc/fstab` to have the secondary distro mounted `/boot` and `/` under i.e. `/secondary/root` & `/secondary/boot`.
 I'll then make sure my user IDs are synchronized for `/home` usage, copy the `/secondary/boot/` kernels & initramfs images to `/boot`, merge the `/secondary/etc/grub.d/*` type files with `/etc/grub.d/*` (depending on distro) to also include the secondary boot kernels.

The only p.i.t.a. will be that when you update the secondary distro's kernel(s) you'll have to synchronize to the primary/main distro's `/boot`.

A more "clean" solution would be to have two seperate HDDs/SSDs where you can select the boot disk from the BIOS/UEFI with the Distro's each on their own separate disk, just sharing the `/home` with the UIDs/GIDs synchronized.

All the best, it'll be a learning curve and fun challenges. ;)